# My keyboard is not working anymore. Ubuntu 22

Tags: keyboard, 22.04

My keyboard is not working correctly For no specific reason. I just updated my ubuntu version to 22.04. A month later my keyboard decided to stop working. Please help

Comment: Your title says you are running Ubuntu Core 22 as Ubuntu is never just one number for a version. The body says 22.04, which is correct and please edit. What does not correctly mean what is the EXACT problems?

Comment: Question: is the keyboard not working *at all* or are some keys doing strange things? Your question suggests both. Are you using an Asus or Acer device? Have you connected a different/external keyboard in order to check for errors in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to why the keyboard is misbehaving? 

Comment: May be related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1455399/7838).