# Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 not working in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, 22.04, soundcard, microsoft

I updated from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and the keyboard did not work anymore. I had to use the onscreen keyboard to log in. I had a spare keyboard which works, but the Microsoft keyboard is stuck. None of the keys are working.

I have searched the Internet and found no similar problem.

I have tried the following:

- find a driver
- settings -> add keyboard layouts
- install keytouch - does not exist
- install xserver-xorg-input-all - already installed
- different USB port

The keyboard work in boot, but after that it's not working.

Funny thing: I run Virtualbox 6.1.42 and inside a running machine, the keyboard is working fine. I actually run Ubuntu 22.04 LTS inside Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The keyboard is working inside the guest, but not in the host OS.

[image: Virtualbox USB device]
Doesn't look like the keyboard is locked to Virtualbox.

I solved it by I mistake. Because my sound device was not found by aplay, but the system and ALSA found the sound cards. After reading different post this code fixed the sound problem:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

And that code also fixed the missing keyboard. My Ubuntu was missing extra kernel modules.

Comment: Check setting of VMs. Maybe the USB device is in the list dedicated to the guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu is missing extra kernel modules. To install the missing kernel modules open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

Comment: seems like a typo in the second command